# how to filter with two specific individuals in sparql query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web, information-retrieval

I would like to filter to two specific values in sparql query.
example "show the software engineering book published in 2010".
In where, software engineering and 2010 are specific value that i would like to filter.
The following is my RDF dataset...

```
DL_lib:Book_3  rdf:type      DL_lib:Book , owl:NamedIndividual ;
    DL_lib:description   "A software engineer is a person who applies the principles of software engineering to design, develop, maintain, test, and evaluate computer software. The term programmer is sometimes used as a synonym, but may also lack connotations of engineering education or skills. Engineering techniques are used to inform the software development process which involves the definition, implementation, assessment, measurement, management, change, and improvement of the software life cycle process itself. It heavily uses software configuration management which is about systematically controlling changes to the configuration, and maintaining the integrity and traceability of the configuration and code throughout the system life cycle. Modern processes use software versioning." ;
    DL_lib:hasAuthor     DL_lib:Ivan_Marsic ;
    DL_lib:hasISBN       "978-0-672-32990-6" ;
    DL_lib:hasPages      335 ;
    DL_lib:hasTitle      "Software Engineering" ;
    DL_lib:isInCategory  <http://www.semanticweb.org/aungyekyaw/ontologies/2020/8/DL_lib#Computer_Science,_Information_and_General_Works> , <http://www.semanticweb.org/aungyekyaw/ontologies/2020/8/DL_lib#004-Computer_programming,_programs_&_data> ;
    DL_lib:locatedIn     "HEC" ;
    DL_lib:published     2012 ;
    DL_lib:publishedBy   DL_lib:Pearson_Education ;
    DL_lib:writeBy       DL_lib:Ivan_Marsic .
```

Comment: **without knowing the dataset**, especially it's RDF data and graph structure it's **impossible to answer** this. It could be simple triple pattern, or multiple triple patterns or even a filter expression being necessary. But that depends on the dataset ...

Comment: @UninformedUser thank for your comment sir, i have edited my question to answer this.

Comment: It's as simple as is: Use triple patterns and set the parts you already know - without reading about SPARQL I doubt that providing a query here is useful, but I'll do it once. The rest is up to you: `PREFIX DL_lib: <PUT_NAMESPACE_HERE> SELECT * WHERE {?book DL_lib:hasTitle      "Software Engineering" ; DL_lib:published     2012 .}`

Comment: I would like to filter those instances with && operator like as `filter regex(str(?var), "software engineering" && ?var = 2012)` . But I do not know that the filter pattern given example is right or not. Because I needed to use filter regex pattern.. Thank you